# Delete rows from one data frame that don't exist in another and combine them

Tags: r, join, merge

I have 2 data frames like so:

df1:

```
ID  A  B  C
1   4  7  5
2   3  8  9
3   6  2  7
4   1  8  6
5   3  9  1
6   7  8  3
```

df2:

```
ID  D  E  F
1   6  8  9
2   2  1  1
3   6  1  9
```

I would like to delete the rows from df1 that don't exist in df2, and then combine the 2 data sets.

Desired output would be:

df3:

```
ID  A  B  C  D  E  F
1   4  7  5  6  8  9
2   3  8  9  2  1  1
3   6  2  7  6  1  9
```

I have tried all the following but nothing gets the correct result:

```
df1 <- df1[(df1$ID %in% df2$ID),]
df1 <- df1[(df2$ID %in% df1$ID),]
df1 <- semi_join(df1,df2)
df1 <- semi_join(df1,df2, by="ID")
```

I have also tried the other "join" methods, such as "inner_join" and "left_join".

Comment: Use `anti_join` or `setdiff`

Comment: @akrun - I'm afraid anti_join also does not provide the correct result. Can you please elaborate on 'setdiff'?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2["ID"], by = "ID", all.y = T)`.

Comment: @djhurio - thanks but also doesn't give me the right outcome. Perhaps I have some issues with the data.

Comment: @djhurio - I just tried again and merge gave me the required result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
## Random datasets
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, ID = sample(letters[1:24], 20))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = sample(letters[1:24], 20), a = 1, b = 2)

## Rows in common
rows_in_common <- df1$ID[df1$ID %in% df2$ID]

## Columns to use in df2
df2_cols <- 2:3

## Combine both datasets
df3 <- cbind(df1[match(sort(rows_in_common), df1$ID),],
             df2[match(sort(rows_in_common), df2$ID), df2_cols])
```

Comment: thank you but I am still working on getting the required number of rows equal in each data frame.

Comment: I tried the above but get the following error: Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'